# QScintilla how to disable "overfolding"

Tags: c++, qt, qscintilla

I'm trying to use QScintilla 2.8.3 along side Qt5.3 to make a small text editor but I'm having a problem with folding.

As you can see here:

[image]

the end of the folding block does not corespond with the closing bracket.

This is how I'm setting up the lexer and folding:

```
cpplexer->setDefaultFont( font );
cpplexer->setFoldAtElse( true );
cpplexer->setFoldComments( true );
cpplexer->setFoldCompact( true );
cpplexer->setFoldPreprocessor( true );

editor->setLexer( cpplexer );
editor->setFolding( QsciScintilla::BoxedTreeFoldStyle );
```

Is it possible to have the block end on the same line as the closing bracket? Is there a flag for this or do I need to change something in QScintilla's source ?

Comment: looks like an off by one error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just set the [setFoldCompact](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/QScintilla2/classQsciLexerPostScript.html#a277a3c519eca4ef69d73fd45ea4f5ab5)() to true, the documentation says:

> virtual void QsciLexerPostScript::setFoldCompact( bool    fold    )   [virtual, slot]
>
> If fold is true then trailing blank lines are included in a fold
>   block. The default is true.

Turn that off and you'll be good to go.